# Why won't my Xlookup formula fill without errors?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I am trying to use an X-lookup formula, it worked fine last week, to search an order number and then return the corresponding invoice number. I then repeat the same formula to find the invoice amount in a separate column. The formula is : =XLOOKUP(A2,'MOD Order + A2K Inv. Lookup Dat'!D2:D742,'MOD Order + A2K Inv. Lookup Dat'!C2:C742)
[The output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/880tP.png)

I have managed to successfully use the formula for one order number but when I try to autofill, I get NA'S in all the other cells. Even more confusing is that even if I type the formula in an individual cell instead  of filling, I still get an NA even though I know for a fact the order number is referenced in the other lookup tab.

[The lookup array the formula references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWe5m.png)

All of the columns match format wise, there are no missing values. I have been trouble shooting this for an hour. Someone please save me and tell me what is going wrong.

I have triple checked column formats because I assumed this was the main issue but no. Please, this doesn't make sense whatsoever

Edit - In column D of the second image, I had formula =left(A2,10) which isolated the numbers from the text filled order number. I then selected the column and changed the format from "general" to "number" thinking this was enough but it was not and this was the source of the problem.

I needed to copy the now isolated order number and then paste special as values and then click the yellow flag to convert the text to numbers. Thank you BigBen for helping me out!

Comment: My guess is that one of those columns has text-that-looks-like-a-number.

Comment: You need to lock the ranges i.e. `$A2`, `$D$2:$D$742`, and `C$2:C$742`.

Comment: Also, you can do the searches all at once for example `=XLOOKUP(A2:A20,'MOD Order + A2K Inv. Lookup Dat'!D2:D742,'MOD Order + A2K Inv. Lookup Dat'!C2:C742,"No matching values")` than locking the cell references with `$` is not necessary. If you want to autofill, use VBasics advice.

Comment: 1. I should have mentioned I tried a version already where I locked the ranges. Only worked for one cell and I could not get it to fill for other cells.

Comment: BigBen - Man. MAN! Reading this comment made me realize I forgot a step in the process of formatting the data once I copy pasted. I used "=left(A2,10) to isolate the numbers from the order number but I forgot to copy paste the data and then paste special as values and convert text to number. I had only been highlighting the column previously and then changing the format in the ribbon. I am equal parts angry at the time wasted but so relieved to have figured it out

Comment: `=--left(A2,10)` will convert to a number.

Comment: Thank ya kindly!